# Solr stats facet left out some values

Tags: solr, statistics, facet, multivalue

I want to facet over products in Solr and want to retrieve statistics about the categories.
My schema has got a field called categories, a multiValued field.
the problem is, that the statistics left out a bunch of categories. Am I wrong with following query? Obviously, but how do I make it right? Pleeeease help, I'm despairing.

```
q=*:*&rows=0&stats=true&stats.field=product_id&rows=0&stats.facet=categories
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query looks fine, the problem is that it's faceting on a multiValued field:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/StatsComponent

> Computing statistics using stats.facet over a multi-valued field does
>   not work properly.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1782

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks!
but now i have to learn how to compile solr myself und stuff the result into tomcat :-/ no pain no gain